# Unable to read the content of JSON File

Tags: node.js, json

**Library** : node-stream-zip

> Error : SyntaxError: Unexpected token  in JSON at position 0
> at JSON.parse ()
> at StreamZip.

**Code** for **extracting** the content of **manifest.json**

```
const getAppInfoFromManifest = async (productId) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let appId = "";
        let appVersion = "";
        const zip = new StreamZip({
            file: `./files/package${productId}.zip`,
            storeEntries: true,
        });
        zip.on("ready", () => {
            let zipDotTxtContents = JSON.parse(
                zip.entryDataSync("manifest.json").toString("utf8")
            );
            appId = zipDotTxtContents?.id;
            appVersionManifest = zipDotTxtContents?.version;
            zip.close();
            resolve({ appId, appVersionManifest });
        });
        zip.on("error", (err) => {
            console.log(err);
            console.log(`Manifest Parsing Issue for ${productId}`);
            resolve(undefined);
        });
    });
};
```

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/json-schemas/teams/v1.5/MicrosoftTeams.schema.json",
  "manifestVersion": "",
  "version": "",
  "id": "",
  "packageName": "",
  "developer": {
    "name": "",
    "websiteUrl": "",
    "privacyUrl": "",
    "termsOfUseUrl": ""
  },
  "name": {
    "short": "",
    "full": ""
  },
  "description": {
    "short": "",
    "full": ""
  },
  "icons": {
    "outline": "",
    "color": ""
  },
  "accentColor": "",
  "configurableTabs": [
    {
      "configurationUrl": "",
      "canUpdateConfiguration": false,
      "scopes": [
          ""
      ]
    }
  ],
  "composeExtensions": [{
    "botId": "",
    "commands": [{
      "id": "",
      "description": "",
      "title": "",
      "initialRun": true,
      "parameters": [{
          "name": "",
          "description": "",
          "title": ""
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "",
      "description": "",
      "title": "",
      "initialRun": true,
      "parameters": [{
          "name": "",
          "description": "",
          "title": ""
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "",
      "description": "",
      "title": "",
      "initialRun": true,
      "parameters": [{
          "name": "",
          "description": "",
          "title": ""
        }
      ]
    }],
    "messageHandlers": [{
      "type" : "",
      "value" : {
        "domains" : [
          "",
          "",
          ""
        ]
      }
    }]
  }],
  "permissions": [
    "",
    ""
  ],
  "validDomains": [
    "",
    "",
    "",
    ""
  ],
  "localizationInfo": {
    "defaultLanguageTag": "en",
    "additionalLanguages": [
      { "languageTag": "bg",    "file": "bg.json"    },
      { "languageTag": "cs",    "file": "cs.json"    },
      { "languageTag": "de-at", "file": "de-at.json" },
      { "languageTag": "de",    "file": "de.json"    },
      { "languageTag": "en-gb", "file": "en-gb.json" },
      { "languageTag": "es",    "file": "es.json"    },
      { "languageTag": "fr-ch", "file": "fr-ch.json" },
      { "languageTag": "fr",    "file": "fr.json"    },
      { "languageTag": "hr",    "file": "hr.json"    },
      { "languageTag": "hu",    "file": "hu.json"    },
      { "languageTag": "id",    "file": "id.json"    },
      { "languageTag": "it-ch", "file": "it-ch.json" },
      { "languageTag": "it",    "file": "it.json"    },
      { "languageTag": "ja",    "file": "ja.json"    },
      { "languageTag": "nb",    "file": "nb.json"    },
      { "languageTag": "nl",    "file": "nl.json"    },
      { "languageTag": "pl",    "file": "pl.json"    },
      { "languageTag": "pt",    "file": "pt.json"    },
      { "languageTag": "ro",    "file": "ro.json"    },
      { "languageTag": "ru",    "file": "ru.json"    },
      { "languageTag": "sk",    "file": "sk.json"    },
      { "languageTag": "sl",    "file": "sl.json"    },
      { "languageTag": "sr",    "file": "sr.json"    },
      { "languageTag": "tr",    "file": "tr.json"    },
      { "languageTag": "zh",    "file": "zh.json"    }
    ]
  }
}
```

When I am reading the appId and appVersion from the manifest, it's showing syntax error at position 0. I have verified this JSON, it's correct. What's the other way to extract information from this manifest.json?

Comment: Why do you want to read json data through StreamZip? There's no `StreamZip` class in nodejs. Is it installed package you are using in your code?

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-stream-zip

Comment: Read file as a buffer: 
const zip = new StreamZip.async({ file: 'archive.zip' });
const data = await zip.entryData('path/inside/zip.txt');

Comment: Your code is correct. The problem is in inner file

Comment: Actually there was some white spaces in the json file, after cleaning it, now I am able to parse it. Thankyou so much for your suggestions. 